# `git merge --strategy-option theirs` for individual files

Tags: git

Using `git checkout --theirs` or `--ours` is handy for resolving conflicts, but they either take the full "theirs" file or the full "ours" file. It does not merge anything, even in areas where it is easy to merge (i.e. areas where the conflicted file does not show any >>>> and <<<<).

Is it possible to do a kind of `checkout --theirs` where there are conflicts but keep merged areas of the file that where correctly merged?

Said differently, I am looking for something that behaves like `git merge --strategy-option theirs` but at the scale of a single file (because for some other files I'd like to use other merging strategies).

Here is a minimal example to reproduce my issue:

1. We first create a repo with a simple file `a.txt`:

```
$ git init
$ cat > a.txt
lorem
ipsum
dolor
sit
amet

consectatur
adipiscing
elit
some
area
to
change
$ git add a.txt
$ git commit -m 'A'
```

2. In a branch, we edit the file at multiple location (top and bottom parts):

```
$ git checkout -b branch
$ cat > a.txt
lorem
ipsum
dolorB
sit
amet

consectatur
adipiscing
elit
B
some
areaB
change
$ git add a.txt
$ git commit -m 'B'
```

3. In the master branch, we edit only one part of the file (top):

```
$ git checkout master
$ cat > a.txt
lorem
ipsumA
dolorA
sitA
amet

consectatur
adipiscing
elit
some
area
to
change
$ git add a.txt
$ git commit -m 'C'
```

4. When trying to merge, the top part is in conflict but the bottom part could be merged successfully:

```
$ git merge branch
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in a.txt
$ cat a.txt
lorem
<<<<<<< HEAD
ipsumA
dolorA
sitA
=======
ipsum
dolorB
sit
>>>>>>> branch
amet

consectatur
adipiscing
elit
B
some
areaB
change
```

What I would like to have is a merged `a.txt` where each time there is a conflict the HEAD block is used (master) but still merge areas where there is no conflict.

Neither `git checkout --theirs` nor `git checkout --ours` works here:

```
$ git checkout --theirs a.txt
$ cat a.txt
lorem
ipsum
dolorB  <--- NOPE!
sit
amet

consectatur
adipiscing
elit
B
some
areaB
change
```

```
$ git checkout --ours a.txt
$ cat a.txt
lorem
ipsumA
dolorA
sitA
amet

consectatur
adipiscing
elit
some
area  <--- NOPE!
to
change
```

What I would like to have is:

```
lorem
ipsumA
dolorA
sitA
amet

consectatur
adipiscing
elit
B
some
areaB
change
```

Comment: I might have misread your question the first time. Reopened it, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: nw, I wasn't clear enough about why `git merge --strategy-option theirs` wasn't a solution ;)

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to do a kind of `checkout --theirs` where there are conflicts but keep merged areas of the file that where correctly merged?

No, but fortunately:

> Said differently, I am looking for something that behaves like `git merge --strategy-option theirs` but at the scale of a single file (because for some other files I'd like to use other merging strategies).

Here the answer is "yes".  It's just not `git checkout` at all.

The first step is to extract all three input files: merge base version, `ours` version, and `theirs` version.  You can do this manually with:

```
git show :1:path/to/file > path/to/file.base
git show :2:path/to/file > path/to/file.ours
git show :3:path/to/file > path/to/file.theirs
```

(If you're in the appropriate subdirectory already, you can just use `file` three time with the three numbered index slots, and `file.base` etc with the names for the redirections.)

Side note: the `git mergetool` command knows how to do this on its own but might be impractical to use here, as it attempts to one particular command—your chosen merge tool—on all remaining conflicted files.  That is, it does the equivalent of running `git status` and checking for unresolved files, and then does the three-checkouts thing for each such file, but then immediately wants to run the (single) tool on those three files.  (Ideally this particular *part* of `git mergetool`, i.e., the "get three versions" part, ought to be provided as a separate Git command, but it isn't.)

Now that you have the three files, the command that lets you do `git merge -X theirs` on them is not actually `git merge` but rather `git merge-file`:

```
git merge-file --theirs file.ours file.base file.theirs
```

(note that the option is spelled slightly differently, but is still "theirs").  The order of the three named files matters: the first one must be the current or `ours` version and the last one must be the `theirs` version, leaving the base in the middle.

The program writes its output back to the first named file, but in this case if something goes wrong and you want to start over, you can just `git show` again.  If you like the result, move it into place and `git add` it:

```
mv file.ours file; git add file
```

for instance (assuming no `path/to/` part needed).

Comment: You can get all the versions at once with `git checkout-index --stage=all`, so `(set -- $(git checkout-index --stage=all path/to/file); git merge-file --theirs $2 $1 $3)`.

Comment: @jthill: this is true, but the resulting file names are kind of annoying. (This is the part of `git mergetool` that is more helpful here.)

Comment: Thx! I was hopping for more of a (Windows compliant) one-liner but I guess it is not possible, this seems like the best workflow indeed.

Comment: I automated this using Python fwiw: https://gist.github.com/eliemichel/3af4a0cdac2434e16e74f96516571ae7

Comment: @Lithy: if you have bash on your Windows system, it's about 4 lines of bash script (significantly shorter than your Python script) using `checkout-index` as jthill showed, but either way it's not that bad.

Comment: It messes with my workflow to switch to bash just for this, and I don't use LoC as a metric when these lines are settled in a file and not sth I'll have to type over and over. ;)

Comment: I personally avoid Windows (and understand that bash is slow *on* Windows) but I have to believe there's a way to run a bash script without starting bash, since Git-for-Windows uses this... :-) Still, as long as it's done and working...!